# What should I add in my code so I will get the output I want

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a 'Tic-Tac-Toe' game, currently my output chooses a player and ask him to choose a sign for him, it displays the name of the player which is chosen, after this next player has to choose a sign for him, I want help with the code that will ask the other player which was not chosen to choose a sign

```
import random

whose_turn = random.choice(['Player 1', 'Player 2'])
print(f"First Turn: {whose_turn}")
sign_player_1 = input(f"{whose_turn}, Choose a sign for you: ")
sign_player_2 = input(f"Opponent, Choose a sign for you: ")

Actual Output:

First Turn: Player 1
Player 1, Choose a sign for you: X
Opponent, Choose a sign for you: O

Expected Output:
First Turn: {Player chosen}
{Player chosen}, Choose a sign for you: 
{Player not chosen}, Choose a sign for you:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
from random import shuffle

players = ['Player 1', 'Player 2']
shuffle(players)
player1, player2 = players

print(f"First Turn: {player1}")
sign_player_1 = input(f"{player1}, Choose a sign for you: ")
sign_player_2 = input(f"{player2}, Choose a sign for you: ")
```